# About DROWN SSL attack

Tags: tls, openssl

I need some clarification regarding DROWN attack:

1) All and only SLLv2 is vulnerable regardless of the chipper strength?

2) How can I check it with Nmap or sslscan?

3) How it's done?

I have also checked the DROWN Attack website but I wanted to ask and recheck with you guys! :)